# Can't connect to wifi network after upgrading kali Linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, network-interface

I bought a TP-Link WN823N Wifi Adapter and I installed the rtl8192eu driver. Before I upgraded the wifi was connecting but airmon-ng wasn't. This is what was showing:

```
root@kali:~# airmon-ng
PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset
null    wlan0       ??????
```

I didn't mind since I was able to connect to a wifi network. After I did an apt-get update, then apt-get upgrade, then apt-get dist-upgrade I can no longer connect to a wifi network as the mac address of the wifi adapter keeps changing. Now when I type the command airmon-ng:

```
root@kali:~# airmon-ng
PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset
phy0 wlan0        rtl81XXX
```

Although I can now go into monitor mode, I can't connect to a wifi network. I tried `macchanger -p wlan0` and `ifconfig wlan0 hw ether 18:d6:c7:1d:a8:37` but the mac address keeps changing as soon as the wifi is about to connect. When I try a live persistence boot from a usb with the installed drivers, I can still connect to a wifi network.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the dist-upgrade giving you the new version of NetworkManager. NetworkManager now handles MAC address changes and so is conflicting with whatever else is trying to change it. [This](https://blogs.gnome.org/thaller/2016/08/26/mac-address-spoofing-in-networkmanager-1-4-0/) may be of some use to you if you want to have a different MAC address associated with the network. You must change your /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf file and remove the SSID configuration in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections once you've updated the config file. Then of course restart network manager

```
service network-manager restart
```

You will find that that blog post outlines how to get started. But also read the man page to see what options are available. I had the same problem you were describing and now macchanger is obsolete. I go for the **stable** option rather than random but up to you.